# YouTube videos stop loading after 30 seconds

Tags: youtube

Do YouTube videos stop loading after 30 seconds for you?

I'm on Safari 6.0.1 and when I load a YouTube video it stops to play after 30 seconds. If I refresh the page, it happens the same. If I refresh the page and then move the cursor forward, it shows 30 seconds of video from that point.

I've tried to restart Safari but it doesn't work.

On Chrome it happens the same.

Actually in both cases the video seems to continue to load (I can see the grey bar growing), but the video stops to run for some reason.

Any idea?

Comment: Still happening? Stops loading more after 30 seconds, or stops playing?